# How to submit a form which contains mysql generated dropdown lists

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, drop-down-menu

Ive got a property website im working on for a school project http://www.holidayaviemore.com

I have three dropdown lists which have all been generated from a mysql database.

I have added a submit button so that when the options have been selected the database info will display..this is where I am really stuck!

Im not sure what code of functions are needed to diplay the content on the page or on another page..any ideas?  This is the code for the dropdownn boxes and form I have so far..

EDIT
Basically I want the options selected to be displayed on a webpage http://www.holidayaviemore.com shows the dropdown lists

```
<p>Select Options From Below to find property</p>
<form action="#" name="form" id="form" method="post">
<?php


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT availability FROM properties";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='availability'><option value=''>- Availability?--</option>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='". $row['availability']. "'>" . $row['availability'] ."</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";


?>

<?php


$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='bedrooms'><option value=''>--Please Choose Bedrooms  Bedrooms--</option>";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['bedrooms'] . "'> " . $count . "</option>";
$count++;
}
echo "</select>";

?>


<?php


$sql = "SELECT sleeps_min FROM properties LIMIT 12";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='sleeps_min'><option value=''>--Please Choose Guests--</option>";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['sleeps_min'] . "'> " . $count . "</option>";
$count++;
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<input type="submit" name="" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Comment: can't understand exactly what you want??

Comment: Why are you setting option value to some field value of a table and displaying count? I would say it should be overwise or it should be $count in both places

Comment: i want the data thats been selected from the dropdown lists to be displayed

Comment: Please clarify a little bit.
You are displaying all 3 dropdowns from the properties table and then you want to search relevant properties also from the same table??

Comment: Be more clear please, your intentions are quite vague.

Comment: yes..displaying the fields availability, bedrooms and sleeps_min from a table called properties.  When the availabilty option, number of bedrroms and sleeps min options are selected, I then what to display this result on another web page

Comment: so i need a statment that would say something like..display results from dropdown lists where availability ="", bedrooms="" and sleeps_min=""

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this. You need to see if form already submitted and add `selected` in `option` tag where it needed.

```
<p>Select Options From Below to find property</p>
<form action="#" name="form" id="form" method="post">
<?php


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT availability FROM properties";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='availability'><option value=''>- Availability?--</option>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(isset($_POST['availability']) and $row['availability'] == $_POST['availability']){
      echo "<option value='". $row['availability']. "' selected>" . $row['availability'] ."</option>";
  }
  else{
      echo "<option value='". $row['availability']. "'>" . $row['availability'] ."</option>";
  }
} 
echo "</select>";


?>

<?php


$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='bedrooms'><option value=''>--Please Choose Bedrooms  Bedrooms--</option>";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(isset($_POST['bedrooms']) and $row['bedrooms'] == $_POST['bedrooms']){
      echo "<option value='" . $row['bedrooms'] . "' selected> " . $count . "</option>";
  }
  else{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['bedrooms'] . "'> " . $count . "</option>";
  }
$count++;
}
echo "</select>";

?>


<?php


$sql = "SELECT sleeps_min FROM properties LIMIT 12";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='sleeps_min'><option value=''>--Please Choose Guests--</option>";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(isset($_POST['sleeps_min']) and $row['sleeps_min'] == $_POST['sleeps_min']){
      echo "<option value='" . $row['sleeps_min'] . "' selected> " . $count . "</option>";
  }
  else{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['sleeps_min'] . "'> " . $count . "</option>";
  }
$count++;
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<input type="submit" name="" value="GO" />
</form>
```